# Python Paho client publish failures with at least 1 missed publsh

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am writing a python client using paho-mqtt, I use publish() to publish data using established connection.

```py
mqttc = mqtt.Client()
...
while True:
    ...
    rc = mqttc.publish(topic, data)
```

But the server will time me out. However, I do not get the timeout until I call publish again.

I got rc in the order of:

```py
(0, 1)
delay
(0, 2)
[Errno 32] Broken pipe
(1, 3)
```

Using Wireshark, I see that as I publish the 2nd time, the connection is reset. But I don't get the "Broken pipe" until my 3rd publish. I tried supplying on_disconnect callback and it is also only called after 3rd publish.

What is the right way to call publish and be notified that the publish has failed immediately? Also, the "Broken pipe" message does not appear to be an exception. How do I prevent it from printing?

Comment: It would be great if you provide minimal functional example. Your question is missing many lines and some of them could reveal, where is the problem. Question: do you call anywhere **any sort of `loop` function**? Quote from doc: **These functions are the driving force behind the client. If they are not called, incoming network data will not be processed and outgoing network data may not be sent in a timely fashion.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted at by @jan-vlcinsky you need to include a call to either start the client network loop in the background or run the loop in the foreground.

E.g.

```
mqttc = mqtt.Client()
mqttc.loop_start()
...
while True:
    ...
    rc = mqttc.publish(topic, data)
```

Or

```
mqttc = mqtt.Client()
...
while True:
    ...
    rc = mqttc.publish(topic, data)
    mqttc.loop()
```